# unable to access the browser conrols created dynamically through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have dynamically created the controls (textbox and checkbox) through javascript.
i.e each time I click the addrow button a new row is generated.

But I am unable to access the  newly created elements through code behind.

Please assist :)

---

-----------aspx file---------------
     
    Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name = "chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
    }

</script>

 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />&nbsp;
    <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk" />
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not possible to get the dynamically created controls using java-script by `ID`.

But I thing you can use `name` property of the control in while creating it through java-script.

And I think then you can get in `Request.Forms` collection.

The id property only identifies the tag within the DOM.  The [name property](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) allows the tag to be posted back as part of a form.  An ASP.NET control, or an HTML element with `runat=server`, automatically gets both the name and id properties assigned.

But the controls created by `java-script` you need to have the `name` property specified.

References :- [Form Post Values using plain html controls in ASP.NET web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435853/form-post-values-using-plain-html-controls-in-asp-net-web-forms/16633439#16633439)

### Another link

http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=28493

### Edit -1

suppose I have created a `input type='text' name='companyname'`
then I can get values as follows

```
string companyname = Request.Form["companyname"];
```

Suppose I am creating an input as in question

```
var element2 = document.createElement("input");
element2.name='companyname'
```

Add this element to form

```
cell3.appendChild(element2);
```

And you can get it on code behind as

```
 string companyname = Request.Form["companyname"];
```

Comment: `Though it is not possible to get the dynamically created controls using java-script by ID` Please read the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property

Comment: The OP is creating controls in java-script not in code behind.

Comment: Check his code with `Request.Form[]`. It gives null. Not working

Comment: @Murali at which event you are looking??

Comment: `Request.Forms` will be accessible through out the page life cycle, what ever  the event it is. :)

Comment: Shekar : I am blank :D ... Because recently i started working with dot net developement :) can you please post the code. :)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I use dynamic (JS-created) controls all the time, using similar method (adding rows dynamically), and Request.Form[] is the way to go. OP is missing `name` attribute on the `input type='text'`, and checkboxes (I believe) only get sent in POST requests if they are checked (value="on" or something?). Also, the `name` property should have an incrementing ID (number) appended to it each time `addRow()` is called. Upvoting!

Comment: even i wondered who downvoted and i dont know why? thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to access the control values from code behind because those are not server controls.the controls which have the attribute **runat="server"** can only be accessed from code behind.

As a workaround, you can send the values to a web service using AJAX, and you can process it from there.

Comment: Wrong. You can access them if they are submitted via a POST request, but you don't get the automatic assignment to a server-side control because they weren't in the Viewstate. Use Request.Form["controlname"] to access the posted data.